# How can I change my page name in Wordpress? Do I need to edit my URL .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My first post so I hope someone can help :)

I need to change http://designoriginal-test.co.uk/ef-travel**/portfolio** to http://designoriginal-test.co.uk/ef-travel/**exhibitions**

How can I go about doing this? There is no 'physical' page in the Wordpress backend so I am not able to change the slug manually.

Thanks in advance!

Zak

Comment: Is `ef-travel` the slug of a custom taxonomy? This would explain the absence of _physical_ page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No ef-travel is the homepage of the site. http://designoriginal-test.co.uk is a test server with multiple sub-domains for individual sites.

Comment: Ok... and is there any reference to `portfolio` in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Where can I find my .htaccess file? (Sorry!)

Comment: Portfolio is a custom post type that is set up on the site - you would have to rename that to change your listings page. How you change it depends upon how it has been created, via code or a plugin.

Comment: Hi @SimonPollard, it was already there when I purchased the theme so I am assuming it is not from a plugin.

Comment: I've noticed (also @SimonPollard did) your `portfolio` is a CPT, so there's no need to check `.htaccess`. Anyway, just for you to know, `.htaccess` should be located in your WP root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your site's source code I see `body` has classes `post-type-archive` and `post-type-archive-portfolio`, so it's not a taxonomy archive but a post type archive.

```
<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-portfolio nictitate-builder nictitate-header-style-1">
```

So, `portfolio` is a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types). This allows two possibilities:

> **You're using a plugin to handle CPT's** (eg: [Custom Post Types UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)).

In this case, you should have a submenu in your WP Dashboard where you could rename the post type.

> **Your CPT's are defined in your custom theme's (or custom plugin) source code**

In this case, you should locate there (check your `functions.php`) some piece of code like this:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio', … );
```

where you'll be able to rename the portfolio too.

In both cases I recommend you to backup your Database first. And if you're editing some source code files, backup them too before making changes.

---

**Update:**

After some research on the theme I've seen there's a [free version](https://wordpress.org/themes/nictitate/) of it. This version requires (via [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)) a custom plugin from the same developer named `Kopa Nictitate Toolkit`.

```
function kopa_register_required_plugins() {
    $plugins = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Kopa Nictitate Toolkit',
            'slug' => 'kopa-nictitate-toolkit',
            'source' => 'http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/kopa-nictitate-toolkit.zip',
```

In this plugin they register the portfolio's CPT. So, check if you have this `kopa-nictitate-toolkit` folder in your `/wp-content/plugins/`. If so, there's a file named `portfolio.php` where they register the Portfolio CPT.

**Edit:**

You'll see that besides registering the CPT

```
register_post_type('portfolio', $args);
```

they also register some custom taxonomies.

```
register_taxonomy('portfolio_project', 'portfolio', $taxonomy_category_args);
register_taxonomy('portfolio_tag', 'portfolio', $taxonomy_tag_args);
```

You'll need to change this too so the theme won't broke. Check [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) docs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @JordiNebot, thanks for your reply. I tried both of these and neither were successful.

My functions.php did not include the word 'portfolio' anywhere and the CPT plugin did not exist on any sub menu of the Wordpress dashboard. After installing a CPT plugin it only allowed me to create new ones, not edit existing ones.

Hmmmmm...

Comment: As you purchases a theme I think the option should be within WordPress admin - you may need to contact the theme authors if you are unable to find out where or how.

Comment: What exactly did you try, @Zak?

Comment: @SimonPollard, I contacted the theme author and they replied saying:

'As far as the issue of changing the permalink according to exhibition is concerned you may have to do URL rewriting in .htaccess file of your server to set custom permalinks according to your requirements. You can also consult any experienced SEO expert as well.'

They weren't too helpful unfortunately.

Comment: A CPT plugin shouldn't let you edit code registered CPT's but you're on the good track. Check all php files in your theme for `register_post_type` or `portfolio`. I suggested `functions.php` because it's a typical place to do such things, but it's not the only one :)

Comment: As @Jordi says it looks like you may have to edit code to fix this one. URL rewriting is quite frankly a ridiculous idea and will cause more problems for you. "portfolio" is a custom post type on your site, you just need to change the settings for it. So do as Jordi says and search your code for register_post_type and see what comes up.

Comment: Really appreciate your help guys (@JordiNebot @SimonPollard).

For some reason there is no 'register_post_type' in any of the theme files. There are 118 instances of the word 'portfolio' so I don't really know where to start :/

I know that a plugin may not be able to provide the URL fix but it has helped me change the post type name to Exhibitions, see image here - http://imgur.com/JzqpKGu.

It's really annoying that something that seems so simple is quite difficult. Any further help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this helps but this is my permalink page - http://imgur.com/AWGxpzg.

And then my results from a Dreamweaver search - http://imgur.com/a/JRae2

@JordiNebot

Comment: Could you please post a link to the theme you purchased, @Zak? Maybe we'll be able to seek any information from there...

Comment: @JordiNebot, this is the theme - http://kopatheme.com/shop/business-wordpress-themes/nictitate-multi-purpose-wordpress-theme/

I've had an idea, what if I were to use Custom Post Types UI to create a completely new post type (with a new name/slug), that inherits the portfolio attributes but has a different name? Just a thought, not sure if this may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: @JordiNebot, I think we may be getting there! There is no kopa-nictitate-toolkit but there is a nictitate-toolkit-ii (which I'm guessing is the premium version).

In this it says -

  # POSTTYPES.
  require NICTITATE_TOOLKIT_II_PATH . 'inc/post-types/portfolio/portfolio.php';

Comment: Did you finally made it, @Zak?

Comment: Yes @JordiNebot you have been a hero! Thank you so much for your help, I could not have done it without you!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the page and change the page name and its Permalink

Comment: From the question: "There is no 'physical' page in the Wordpress backend"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The page does not appear in the 'Pages' back end area of Wordpress. So I believe it is more complicated than this.